# Combining a set of fractions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof

Consider the set {1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, ..., 1/n}

Choose any two numbers x and y and replace them with x + y + xy

For example, if we choose the numbers 1 and 1/2 , we will replace them by 1 + 1/2 + 1/2 = 2.

If we keep repeating this process until only  number remains, what is the final number?

So far I understand that this will result in all possible combinations of the terms for example:
{a, b, c, d} = a+b+c+d+ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd+abc+abd+acd+bcd+abcd

How do we compute this sum effectively though?

Comment: not a programming question

Comment: Pretend your list looks like `{a,b,c, ...}` and just start writing out what your procedure produces. You should notice a pattern.

Comment: http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/numbercombine.pdf

Comment: `n`, and like the man said, this margin is too small to contain the marvellous proof ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

From a strictly programming perspective, ignoring the closed-form solution, the simple way to evaluate this expression (taking, arbitrarily, the terms in order) is a loop, starting with an accumulator of 0, that adds to it each term *and* the product of that term with the accumulator’s value so far.  (No syntax because no language specified, among other reasons.)